# How many messages can I star? Is there any rate limiting?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

[This](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2182854#2182854) got me curious:

> Like you start with 500 stars. The first one leaves you with 499, the second with 497, the third with 494...

Is this already in place? Does it mean I can use only 500 stars then can't star anymore?

If the above isn't true, what are the limits?

Thank, and happying starring!

Comment: That [was an idea, not a statement.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2182842#2182842)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Per the FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#star), you're limited to 20 stars per room, per day and there's no cumulative limit.

As a history lesson, there used to not be any upper limit on the number of stars you could cast. However, after a select group of Tavernfolk proved that they couldn't control themselves, [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek) did us all a favour and requested that a limit be established.

Comment: Thanks, with Shog one can never be sure enough. :)